# PHP Simple HTML Dom parser returns 0

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I use PHP Simple HTML Dom parser to get some elements of a page. Unfortunately, I get as a result 0 or 1... I would like to get the innerHTML instead.

Here is a photo of the dom:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

    //  We take the url we want to scrape
    $URL = 'https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000033011065&dateTexte=20160821';

    //  Curl init
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //  We get the html
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($result);


    // Find all article blocks
     foreach($html->find('div.data') as $article) {
     $item['title']     = $article->find('.titreSection', 0)  ->plaintext;

     $resultat[] = "<p>" + $item['title']."</p></br>";

     }

     include 'vue_scrap.php';
?>
```

Here is the code of my view:

```
foreach ($resultat as $result){
        echo $result;
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which line gives you 0/1 instead of inner html data?

Comment: In my view I have the following code printing the 0: foreach ($resultat as $result){
  echo $result;
 }

Comment: use `$html = str_get_html($result);` instead of `$html = new simple_html_dom(); $html->load($result);`

Comment: It does not work: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::loadHTML()

Answer (score 0):

In fact I just did a mistake with that line:

```
$resultat[] = "<p>" + $item['title']."</p></br>";
```

The correct version is:

```
$resultat[] = "<p>".$item['title']."</p></br>";
```